# Is it possible to compile Typescript files locally but not on the build server?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, typescript, build-server

I've added Typescript to my build process, but I'm getting the `Write to file failed` error because the destination js file is Read Only, and this is because I'm including the emitted js file in TFS.

I know I could remove the js file from TFS and always generate on the fly, but I don't want to do that because I want to include them in the project and the deployment to the build server will fail if I do that with files that aren't in TFS.

I could [use a pre-build step to remove the Read Only attributes](http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/05/03/typescript-emit-error-write-to-file-failed-how-to-resolve/) but that seems kludgy.

What I really want is to include the js files and have the precompiled on build, *but only on my local dev machine and not on the build server*. I would even be happy with compiling them on save and **not** on build. But I can't find a way to accomplish either of these.

Comment: I think you should work on getting your build server to compile the typescript files without failing. That's the issue that needs resolving.

Comment: It fails because the file is read only, and that's just how TFS works, without hacks to get around it. But now I'm starting to think I should just not include the js files in TFS in the first place.

Comment: yeah, don't include the js files. There's really no need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you stated that you want to include them in your project which is why you want to include the js files in version control (TFS), but IMO that is not the approach to take, for the same reason you do not check in your dll's.

In the case of TypeScript the *.ts files are your source code and *.js files are your compiled output which are easily reproduced by your build process whether that be MsBuild or gulp/grunt.

If you are using the bundling/minification libraries then you need not worry as the files included in them are based upon the file structure and not upon the the project structure. You can simply include the necessary files/directories within the necessary bundle(s).

I know this may not be the answer that you were looking for, but I feel like it has a place as a potential solution in regards to how to handle the output of js files from ts source code.

Comment: After reading your answer, I think I am persuaded that you're right. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: It is a slight shift in thinking as many of us are used to including our JS files in our projects and therefore feel compelled to include them even after migrating/upgrading/changing to TypeScript.

Comment: With appropriate entries in web.config the server can serve the JS file when the TS file is requested. This allows you to reference the TS file in your markup, which removes a maintenance boobytrap by indicating the true source code.